# accessing indexPath.row field variables

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

In xcode, I am trying to add some way to log what is deleted from a tableview.

Here is my delete code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete object from database
    [context deleteObject:[self.contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }

   NSManagedObject *device = [self.contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSLog(@"Deleting %@ ", [device valueForKey:@"name1"]);

    // Remove contact from table view
    [self.contacts removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

}

all fairly standard stuff except for these two lines

```
       NSManagedObject *device = [self.contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSLog(@"Deleting %@ ", [device valueForKey:@"name1"]);
```

I'm trying to access the data in the fields in this row before it is deleted, but NSLog returns null. I've tried other variations, and had one version that returned the variables in the previous row!

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you are trying to access the data after you have deleted it. Move this

```
    NSManagedObject *device = [self.contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSLog(@"Deleting %@ ", [device valueForKey:@"name1"]);
```

before this

```
[context deleteObject:[self.contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: thanks doug and paul.  for some reason i thought the delete was happening a few lines lower but i guess that just removes it from the tableview iteslf

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to print an object after you have deleted it and committed this action by saving.

You could just move the following lines:

```
 NSManagedObject *device = [self.contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 NSLog(@"Deleting %@ ", [device valueForKey:@"name1"]);
```

above your call to `[context save:&error]`